# Symfony Doctrine persisting one to one mandatory relation issue

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm having some issues when trying to persist an entity with a mandatory One To One relation, I'm getting the message : **SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'deliveryMode_id' cannot be null**

So, I have a SHOP entity :

```
class Shop{

    ...

    /**
    * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="acme\Bundle\DeliveryBundle\Entity\DeliveryMode", cascade={"all"}, orphanRemoval=true)
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
    * @Assert\Valid
    */
    private $deliveryMode;
    ...
}
```

I'm also having a DeliveryMode entity without any link to the Shop entity (that is not a bi-directional relation).

I'm having working form types associated to Shop and DeliveryMode (deliveryModeFormType is nested into the shop one).

When I try (after validation operations succeeded) to do a

```
$entityManager->persist($new_shop);
```

I have the error I mentioned above.

I have tried to change 
    nullable=**false**
to
    nullable=**true**

And it works well with persisting correctly the delivery mode attached to the shop, and of course the shop.

So I think that proves all is right, is it a possible bug of Doctrine 2.4.4? Actually it seems that the SQL insertion of the shop is done before the deliveryMode insertion, so SQL throws an exception because we have a not nullable property on the shop deliveryMode. 
As soon as the not nullable restriction is removed the issue disappears, weird thing, thank you for your help!

Edit: When putting the database operation into a doctrine transaction, that works perfectly, I think there's kind of a priority management that fails through Doctrine ORM, DeliveryMode should be inserted before the Shop and that's not the case

Comment: I don't see anything wrong. Try dumping `$deliveryMode` at different points in the execution and make sure it's being handled correctly. You could, for example, set listeners in your `Type` for `FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA`, etc.

Comment: By the way, you may want to try https://github.com/raulfraile/LadybugBundle for easy dumping.

Comment: Thanks for help FyodorX, Ladybug is a great tool! When doing a :
Ladybug_dump_die($shop->getDeliveryMode());
Just before the flush, all is ok, but i'm still having the error mentioned in my first message when flushing

Comment: Can you post `Shop`'s `setDeliveryMode()`?

Comment: Of course : 

`public function setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode $deliveryMode){
     $this->deliveryMode=$deliveryMode;
     return $this;
    }`

Comment: Try adding `$this->deliveryMode->setShop($this);` before the `return`.

Comment: Actually that's a uni-directional relation, so DeliveryMode has no setShop Method (because DeliveryMode can also linked to other entities different from Shop)

Comment: I edited my first post, when flushing through a transaction that works..

Comment: What happens if you remove the `@Assert\Valid` and `@ORM\JoinColumn` annotations?

Comment: When I remove the `@Assert\Valid` annotation, nothing happens but when I remove the `@Orm\JoinColumn` as I mentioned in my first post that works (deliveryMode is inserted as expected and linked to the shop) because the deliveryMode property becomes nullable, so MySQL does not throw any exception